# How can i share window 7 wireless connection

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, router

I have wireless network card via `USB` for use in `window 7`

Now i have another LAN card and from that  LAN card i want to connect to

`cisco router`

I have done following queseries

1. Which adapter i have to share LAN or wireless
2. The windows automatically gives ip to another adapetr. now what should be the ip of that adapter and its gateway
3. what should be the ip and gateway of interface of router

Answer (score 0):

If the router is a wireless router, It would be easier to setup a WLAN. You can do this from the router's interface once you're connected to it.

Your question isn't clear enough so this is the best I can offer.

Comment: The router is not wireless and its cisco router for networking. I just want to make my second LAN card on computer to act as switch so that it can pass internet to router port , from wireless card